# Custom Payment method is not displayed on frontend

Tags: checkout, payment

I'm stuck with creating simple payment method. It is displayed in admin panel but not on frontend.

In Chrome developer tools I get errors on frontend that are displayed on pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems to me, that corresponding file is not deployed into pub/static folder, though I cleared pub/static and generated directories manualy and then ran bin/magento setup:upgrade, bin/magento setup:di:compile, bin/magento setup:static-content deploy -f. And flushed cache finally.

My Payment method is just a copypasta from this source: [Meetanshi Payment Method](https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-payment-method-in-magento-2/)

My method-renderer.js file:

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
],
function (
    Component,
    rendererList
) {
    'use strict';
    rendererList.push(
        {
            type: 'custompayment',
            component: 'Meetanshi_CustomPayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/custompayment'
        }
    );
    return Component.extend({});
});
```

Thank You in advance!

P.S. Also I'm using custom Magento_Checkout module. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: clear cpanel or cloud cache if enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the issue. It was due to a typo in line 21 of my module's 'checkout_index_index.xml' file:

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Meetanshi_Custompayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer</item>
```

instead of:

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Meetanshi_CustomPayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following commands .

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work(